# How to translate “Wir müssen wissen, wir werden wissen.” into Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

> “Wir müssen wissen, wir werden wissen.” — David Hilbert

> “We need to know, we will know.” — David Hilbert

I was trying to translate this quote into Latin while preserving the parallelism between the two parts but I couldn't come with something satisfying.

Indeed, the future is usually translated with only one word while the necessity isn't.

Comment: Any decent translation should surely preserve the parallelism with Emil du Bois-Reymond's maxim "[_ignoramus et ignorabimus_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoramus_et_ignorabimus)", to which Hilbert's remark was a direct response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an attempt for increased parallelism:

> **Sciendum est, scitum erit.**
> ≈ "It has to be known, it will be known."

Latin typically uses the future perfect thing for an action completed in the future, whereas English often goes with a mere future as in my translation.
The choice of tense also makes the statement strong: knowing will be complete.

I like the syntactical parallelism of having just a participle with a form of *esse* on both sides, and the subject of both clauses is the implicit thing to be known.
(I take the liberty to classify the gerundive as a participle.)
The parallelism falls apart in the active voice.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of it, you lose the repetition of the German sounds but it's probably the best one can do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

You can express the necessity by means of a gerund: *that which must be known*, or **cognoscendum**.
*We shall know what must be known* then becomes

> **Cognoscendum cognoscemus**.

Comment: The meaning is slightly different but that's really interesting

Comment: +1. One can consider using also gerundive n. pl. which seems to be a little better. cf. *Cavebo quae sunt cavenda* (Cic.)

Answer (score 7):

I would say:

> *Oportet scire, sciemus igitur.*
>
> It is needful to know, and so we shall know.

I chose *scire*, because, according to Döderlein's *[Hand-Book of Latin Synonymes](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/33197/33197-h/33197-h.htm)*:

> *scientia*, together with *scire*, involves spontaneous activity, and a perception of truth.

I also added *igitur* (*hence*, *and so*, *accordingly*) to help balance it out. And this is also an example of [chiasmus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12769/use-of-the-chiasmus-in-latin), which was a somewhat poetic way of expressing things in Latin.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another suggestion trying to preserve the parallelism:

> Sciendum est
> Scituri sumus

It is actually a relatively literal translation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm astonished - didn't Hilbert said it in Latin anyway, as an answer to the "Ignorabimus!" cry of duBois-Raymond? **"Nescimus, sed sciemus!"** (Note that what can't be googled does not exist, the phrase return is astonishingly poor. My reference is Meschkowski, "Denkweisen großer Mathematiker", who attributes it to a talk of Hilbert in Berlin, short before his death around the end of war. [Google Books, in German](https://books.google.de/books?id=ILubBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=nescimus%20sed%20sciemus&source=bl&ots=D-Z9JJpxoJ&sig=ACfU3U2LSl-E20iyC6v8KcFih-g-1Gxi4w&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYn9X0m8L0AhVENewKHV5ODxIQ6AF6BAgPEAM#v=onepage&q=nescimus%20sed%20sciemus&f=false))

Comment: The epitaph on his tombstone in Göttingen is in German, I don't know if he ever said it in Latin but this is the first time I've heard it. I'll do some research.

Comment: But he did say it in German! It is quoted right at the start of the chapter on Hilbert in the book you linked. He may also have said *Nescimus, sed sciemus*, but that is not quite the same, is it?

Comment: He said it in German, correct. The question is if he said it in Latin *too*, and if he considered it as the fitting translation. ("müssen" is far more "urgent" than "nescimus") My opinion is yes on both but I lack convincing primary sources.